# Passing Id to URL Parameters and API. URL Parameter gets the ID but id pass null in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to Pass Id from one Page to anither using Class component. Id passing in URL Parameter and Hit the API pass the null value.This is Link to pass Id

```
 <Link to={"/GroupsDetail/"+item.group_Id} >Details</Link>&nbsp;
```

In URL Parameter it works "http://localhost:3001/#/GroupsDetail/32"

Hit the API but it is null value

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6ftP.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fui54.png)

How to get the Url Parameter. I use this one but it didn't works

```
let url = 'http://localhost:0000/api/Group/GroupDetailsDisplay?GroupId='+this.props.match.params.Group_Id;
```

and also try this one

```
  const urll = new URL(window.location.href);
const Id = urll.searchParams.get("Group_Id");
        
        console.log(Id);
        let url = 'http://localhost:0000/api/Group/GroupDetailsDisplay?group_Id='+Id;
```

This is my path route

```
 <Route path="/GroupsDetail" component={GroupsDetail}/>
```

This also returns null.I need to get params value "http://localhost:3001/#/GroupsDetail/32". Share your Idea. Thank you

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text."_

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add the id to your route:

```
 <Route path="/GroupsDetail/:id" component={GroupsDetail}/>
```

And get it:

```
 this.props.match.params.id
```

---

If you send it as a query string parameter like

```
<Link to={"/GroupsDetail?groupId="+item.group_Id}>Details</Link>
```

You can get it via

```
this.props.location.query.groupId
```

Comment: this.props.match.params.id Where i need to pass this and this.props.location.query.groupId where it is come.

Comment: just modify your router like I described to allow id parameter and you get your id in GroupsDetail component with `this.props.match.params.id`

Comment: It return undefined @Suciu Eus

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/smhu6kow/ Check About page in this example. It's with components, but if you want to use functional components use `import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';` then   `const params = useParams()` and do a `console.log(params)`